# Adding a customized sidecar to a K8S deployment

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks, istio

I wish to use a Mutating WebHook or Istio to automatically inject a Sidecar container and a shared volume between the existing container and sidecar to a k8s deployment in a remote cluster for log archiving. The issue is that the mount path required for each pod differs and is provided as a user-provided input.

What would be the best way to pass this user-defined information to the webhook?

Comment: Hi, According to Istio [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/setup/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/#automatic-sidecar-injection) there is option to set up automatic sidecar injection. It also has options for templates and exceptions but it seems very complicated.

Comment: Yes, I would be willing to use Istio, However, there is no clear documentation wether the injected sidecar can be made dynamic using user inputs. ( For example the Volume Mount path )

Answer (score 2):

The best place to store that kind of data for the mutating webhook to read from are [annotations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/).

More useful [information](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#extending-with-annotations) about annotations and webhooks with examples. [Annotations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api) can also be accessed from containers inside a pod.

Note that if the mount path is different for different pods, then we need to get those paths from somewhere.